# Xcode deletes my file because of full disk space. How to recover?

Tags: ios, xcode, recovery

Xcode deleted my Swift file as my disk is full. How do I recover them? It has more than 1000 lines of code!

Comment: Check your Time Machine backups and see if it's there.

Comment: @PaulR I don't have time machine backups.

Comment: Even if you have been reckless enough not to have set up an external drive for Time Machine, you may still have local Time Machine backups at `/Volumes/MobileBackups` - check there...

Comment: Disk Drill to restore deleted files.check in http://www.cleverfiles.com/

Comment: @PaulR Where is the /Volumes/MobileBackups located? I'm sorry I will do use time machine immediately.

Comment: Um, that is the full path: `/Volumes/MobileBackups` - `cd` there via the command line in Terminal or open it in Finder using `Go to Folder...`.

Comment: @PaulR Looks like I don't have the mobile backup either...

Comment: OK, well, commiserations then - I guess you learned an important lesson today: if you work without any kind of backup strategy then sooner or later you *will* lose important files.